Dump vs multi-search
I have a list of values for a handful of attributes.
For each value, I want to retrieve a single document that matches that value (if there are multiple, I only need the first one that comes up).
What is the most optimal way to do so?
I came up with these two options:

Multisearch which is clunky because it often times out, so I have to batch my queries in groups of 10 or so...
Aggregation on each of these attributes and dumping the data, then loading it in a hashtable and do lookups.

Size of my data: ~100k documents in my index; ~1000s of values or documents to retrieve.
As a side note, the reason I am trying to optimize this is because I have to run this process a 100 times or so, and my index is actually 100 times as big, but I pre-filter by an attribute with a different value each time.
